Jacobian of exponential map
I am playing around with the coarea formula and came across the problem of finding the Jacobian of the exponential map.
Let $G$ be a compact, semisimple Lie group with associated Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ (endowed with an ad-invariant metric). Let $\exp: \mathfrak g \longrightarrow G$ be the exponential map (at the identity). Let $R > 0$ be the injectivity radius, then $\exp$ is differentiable in the set $\{X \in \mathfrak g : |X| < R\}$, and therefore there exists a differential $D\exp_X: T_X \mathfrak g \longrightarrow T_{\exp(X)} G$. We define the Jacobian $J_{\exp}: \{X \in \mathfrak g : |X| < R\} \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ via
$$J_{\exp}(X) := \det(D\exp_X \, D\exp_X^*)^{\frac 12}$$
for all $X \in \{X \in \mathfrak g : |X| < R\}$, where $\bullet^*$ denotes the adjoint.
Question: Can anyone provide a formula or reference for the Jacobian of the exponential map?
Thanks in advance.

You probably mean "equipped with an invariant non-degenerate symmetric  bilinear form" instead of "metric" as an invariant metric only exists for a compact group.

@Nandor I changed the assumptions accordingly. I assume now compactness. Thanks for pointing that out.

You idtentify $T_X\mathfrak g$ with $\mathfrak g$ (as it is a vector space). Then you identify $T_{exp(X)}G$ with $T_eG$ by the differential of the left-multiplication by $\exp(X)$. The map $\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{g}$ you get in this way is $\exp(ad(X))$ and you are asking for the determinant of $\exp(ad(X))\exp(ad(X^*))$. But $\det(\exp(ad(X))=\exp(\mathrm{tr}\ ad(X))=\exp(0)=1$, as the Lie algebra is semisimple, hence unimodular.

Look in Helgason's Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces.  He gives a formula for the Jacobian of the differential of the exponential map.  I don't know the history that well, but I think that such formulae are due originally to some combination of Cartan and Weyl.  Probably, Helgason's notes at the end of the relevant chapter contain some comment on this.  (I don't have my copy handy at the moment.)

Helgason cites his 1958 paper "On the Riemannian curvature of homogeneous spaces", but that paper mentions it's equivalent to a result in Chevalley's 1948 book on Lie groups.

@user17945 Helgason later said that he probably should have put more of that material in the textbook.  To make up for the lack, he handed out offprints of that 1958 paper to his Lie Groups classes.
